# How can I make LightDM the default display manager?

Tags: login-screen, lightdm, display-manager

I have LightDM installed and can start it with `sudo start lightdm`. But at boot, GDM is still the default. How can change this so LightDM is loaded automatically at boot instead of GDM?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Will prompt you to make it default. More information here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: I have the feeling it is not working $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
[sudo] password for user: 
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing

Comment: @ seb, I get the same warning and my issue (http://askubuntu.com/questions/63134/how-to-get-the-proper-lightdm-theme) has not been fixed... I'm quite certain I'm running LightDM because entering "lightdm --test-mode" in a console gives me the exact same login screen.

Comment: I have the same problem. Googling reveals we are not alone, but there appears to be no solution.

Answer (score 10):

`/etc/X11/default-display-manager` should currently contain something else than `lightdm`.

Like I [answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59978/lightdm-is-running-but-does-not-display-on-login/71009#71009) in another question, since LightDM starts on your machine, you should reference the binary in `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/sbin/lightdm" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable gdm.service  
$ sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service
```

Here enable starts service at boot. You can know more about it [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd#Basic_systemctl_usage).