# How to remove the old gdm

Tags: login, gdm, 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make LightDM the default display manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58023/how-can-i-make-lightdm-the-default-display-manager)

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 beta and all of its changes are now working and let me testing them, but the only missing thing is the lightdm's new theme which doesn't work and insted I have the old gdm login screen. My question is how to replace it with the newest lightdm.

EDIT: I figured out what is the problem which is really different from the possible duplicate inserted here!!!. The problem is that I need to install a package called unity-greeter to make the new Ubuntu lightdm theme work. So please guys reopen the question as I want to answer it with what I found.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and choose lightdm as default login manager (or simply remove `gdm` package).

Comment: Actually I tried removing gdm, but nothing happens!!. and when I trying  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm, I got this:

dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing

Comment: maybe my lightdm theme not installed correctly.. if so how to repair it?

Comment: I have the same problem.  I can't reconfigure lightdm as I get the same error message.  This is quite an old question now - any ideas?