# LightDM is running but does not display on login

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

LightDM is installed and running by default as a part of the Beta release. Yet, LightDM is not displayed at login time, rather a primitive, GDM like manager is the one we find at login time.

I tried the command
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

which gave the result  :

dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing

while,

sudo stop gdm 
gives
stop: Unknown job: gdm
(as GDM is not installed in the Beta Release)

sudo start lightdm
gives
start: Job is already running: lightdm

So now, how do we make LightDM appear at login time?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? I suppose what you call "a primitive GDM-like display manager" is exactly LightDM.

Comment: I have already used LightDM in alpha 3. It isnt like it at all. Rather like the one default in Alpha 1

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lightdm`

That should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/854337) for this issue.
If lightdm starts sucessfully on your machine, the [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/854337/comments/4) is to manually set absolute path to `lightdm` in the `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` file:

> sudo su
>   echo "/usr/sbin/lightdm" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager
>   exit

(when I experienced this problem on my installation, there was only the binary name `lightdm` in the file.)

Comment: Exactly what I needed to sort out my problem.

Comment: This did not work for me. My default manager is already set to lightdm, but my screen is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

LightDM is installed but I suppose it's still using the greeter from the alpha. Just apt-get purge lightdm and lightdm-gtk-something (it will also remove ubuntu-desktop). Then install again ubuntu-desktop and unity-greater will be installed alongside lightdm.

Comment: Don't do that! Purging your display manager is not good.