# How to get the proper LightDM theme?

Tags: 11.10, themes, lightdm

I've been using Oneiric since the second Alpha (had to, my new system refused to run any older Ubuntu version) and I've never been able to get the nifty LightDM theme I'm seeing everywhere. Instead, I'm alway seeing this theme instead:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvGhg.jpg]

Can anyone explain to me how to change / fix this?

Also when I do a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, it gives the following warnings, could that be related to my problem?:

```
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing         
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May seem silly, but have you `sudo apt-get install lightdm unity-greeter`? If I recall correctly `lightdm` *should* be downloaded as a part of the ubuntu-desktop meta package - so if you've missed that package, try installing it. You should also have the `unity-greeter` packaged. It should drop right into place after installing.

You might need to manually switch to lightdm:

- [How can I make LightDM the default display manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58023/how-can-i-make-lightdm-the-default-display-manager)