# How do I make GDM the default display manager?

Tags: lightdm, gdm, display-manager

I believe my question says what I am trying to achieve.

Steps I tried to make `gdm` my default display manager:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` than select gdm as my default.
2. Edit `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` and change its content to

   ```
   /usr/sbin/gdm
   ```

After the above two steps I `logged out` myself and after that when I see my login screen it still shows `lightdm` as my display manager.

What am I doing wrong here.?

Comment: Have you uninstalled lightdm..?

Comment: @Uri Herrera This should not be necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make LightDM the default display manager?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58023/how-can-i-make-lightdm-the-default-display-manager)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You seem to have configured gdm correctly, but you did not actually stop lightdm. Logging out doesn't stop it.

After doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`, you need to stop lightdm

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

and start gdm

```
sudo service gdm start
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: This kills the session. Stopping the a display manager while running a desktop session will also kill your desktop environment.

Comment: A lot of damage by following these steps. stop on lightdm gave me blank non X screens.. Crazy.