# Can I "upgrade" Ubuntu MATE 14.04 to Ubuntu GNOME 14.04?

Tags: gnome, mate

I am an Ubuntu MATE 14.04 user, because I wanted the old GNOME 2 UI, but now, I decided to upgrade. Can I upgrade to Ubuntu GNOME 14.04?

Edit: For those trying to do this: **Use Ubuntu GNOME.**

Comment: No, not upgrade, but you can install Gnome along Mate. Not sure it is a good idea, though.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yep, wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can install it, but not as an upgrade.

All you need to do is install GNOME as an extra desktop environment, which you can do either through the software centre or the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

To select the environment:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you do this, your system will be a mess, full of redundant apps and icons. It's better do format and do a clean Ubuntu Gnome install.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich if you choose to reverse the installation, this guide should help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244654/remove-ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: And the gnome shell - that is the newest stable gnome build?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich yes - the latest stable build available for 14.04

Comment: Default display manager: gdm, lightdm, which one?

Comment: @DevRobot It would uninstall GNOME, but wouldn't it uninstall also my MATE?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich No it wouldn't uninstall mate - and if you want the display manager of gnome, use gdm - find out how to set it here: http://askubuntu.com/a/151358/146980

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is posible to install GNOME from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

After rebootin, you must select the desktop environment you want (MATE or GNOME) before you log in

Comment: You don't need to add the PPA, since gnome-shell is available to install by default.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. 
Command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Next reconfiguration login manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```