# Window switcher appears randomly on any monitor in KDE

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, kde, application-switcher

I am using 3 monitors and when I am switching between windows with Alt-TAB, windows switcher appears randomly on one of them.

Is it possible to configure window switcher to appear on only one monitor or appear on all monitors or in any other way remove randomness?

---

It appears on that monitor, where last window was. Since windows are distributed randomly, window switcher also does.

For example, two subsequent Alt-Tab-s may appear on different monitors, even if mouse is not moving.

Comment: Are you sure it is random, or is it appearing on the same monitor as the mouse pointer?

Answer (score 0):

On my system (**Ubuntu 16.04 Unity Interface**) the Window Switcher appears on the monitor where the mouse pointer is. You could get the same features in **18.04** or others in **19.04** if the Unity Interface is installed:

- [How can I make LightDM the default display manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58023/how-can-i-make-lightdm-the-default-display-manager)

Of course this means abandoning KDE which you may not want to do!

Alternately, you can explore other Window Switchers via Gnome extensions:

- [Alternate Tab GNOME shell extension](https://fedoramagazine.org/alt-tab-gnome-shell-extension/)